# How to trigger the html5 video tag download event from javascript/angular

Tags: javascript, angular, html5-video

We are currently using the HTML5 `video` tag to show a video on our site, which the user should be able to download if they want to keep it for future use. The HTML5 `video` tag provides a default option to download the video (marked by a black border in the image), however, we are required to provide additional control to let the user do the download (marked by a red border in the image.)
[image]

Is there a way to trigger the event that html5 video uses to do the download from javascript/angular?

Comment: hi @Ketu im facing the same problem, did you get the solution yet

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Brooo Answer please @Ketu you find away ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use file-saver module to download a blob file
[npm-file saver module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver)

Comment: I am getting cors issue with file saver as well.
the video downloads if I select the 3 vertical dots and select the download option in the resulting menu
I will check if enabling cors will change something and let me allow to download the video.

Answer (score 0):

After a little research I've found a solution, but it is needed to create a link instead of button to make it work. You just need to point to your video resource in that link, open it in new tab/window and add `download` attribute to it:

```
<a href="https://example.com/link-to-res.mp4" target="_blank" download>dl link</a>
```

You can also try to create this link and open it programmatically inside onclick function on your download button:

```
clickFunction() {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = "https://example.com/link-to-res.mp4";
    a.download = "";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

Hope that will help out with your problem.

Comment: I tried the first approach, however when I click on the link it opens it into new tab.
used code 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>The video element</h1>

    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source
        src="https://www.quackit.com/video/pass-countdown.ogg"
        type="video/ogg"
      />
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    <a
      href="https://www.quackit.com/video/pass-countdown.ogg"
      target="_blank"
      download
    >
      link
    </a>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: the second approach as well has opened a new tab and shows the video in the middle of the page.
did not download the video directly.

Comment: @Ketu There could be a problem if you're trying to download from site which is not the same as your origin URL. According to changes mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/02/chrome-65-deprecations#block_cross-origin_wzxhzdk5a_download there is no way to download from cross-origin source (I assume that you're using Chrome).

Comment: ohh, that's a bummer.
the video downloads if I select the 3 vertical dots and select the download option in the resulting menu. I was wondering if there is a way to trigger this download event using javascript.